# List of abbreviations

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

Is there a way to get an alphabetical list of abbreviations automatically? At the moment I have:

```
\begin{longtable}{ll}

APC & antigeen-presenterende cel \\

\end{longtable}
```

I use `longtable` because my table is very long.

Comment: You should consider the `nomencl` or `glossaries` packages.

Comment: Do you mean a table that presents the rows in sorted order, independent of the order of rows in the source file?

Comment: I mean in sorted order

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As egreg said, look at the `nomencl` and `glossaries` packages.

Quick and dirty for `nomencl`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Here is some text, where we use APC.\nomenclature{APC}{antigeen-presenterende cel}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Run

```
pdflatex; makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t liselot.nlg -o liselot.nls liselot.nlo; pdflatex
```

on it to obtain

[image: sample output nomencl]

Quick and dirty for `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apc}{%
name={APC},%
description={antigeen-presenterende cel}%
}

\begin{document}
Here is some text, where we use \gls{apc}.

\printglossary[style=long]
\end{document}
```

Run

```
pdflatex; makeindex -s liselot2.ist -t liselot2.glg -o liselot2.gls liselot2.glo; pdflatex
```

on it to obtain

[image: sample output glossaries]

Comment: Thank you! And if I wanted to leave out the page number, what should I do?

Comment: @MusLiselot For the `nomencl` version, just delete the `refpage` option when loading the class. For the `glossaries` version, use `\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}`.

Comment: It compiled successfully but nomenclature is not printed ... what can i do i'm using texMaker and i need to know how to add those flags ... thanks

Comment: @TheBeast Texmaker can be configured to use this by editing the makeindex command. I found that it looks for liselot.nlo, but it proceeds nicely if you replace it with %.nlo. However, it still does not print anything.