# Nomenclature; running makeindex

Tags: texshop, nomenclature, mac

I'm new to LaTeX and have been struggling with generating a nomenclature, for several hours...

I have tried to follow this instruction: http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/nomencl.pdf but doesn't know how to "Invoke MakeIndex"...

I have also tried to follow follow the answer here: [List of abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100354/list-of-abbreviations) but how do I do the "Run" step??

I'm really stuck here and a simple answer for a rookie would make my day...

This is an example of what i have been trying to type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Here is some text, where we use APC.
\nomenclature{APC}{antigeen-presenterende cel}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

I'm using a Macbook with TexShop by the way

Answer (score 2):

If your input file as posted is `nc.tex`

then running these commands in order

```
pdflatex nc
makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o nc.nls nc.nlo 
pdflatex nc
```

should generate the nomenclature and include it in the document.

[image]

`nomencl.ist` is the `makeindex` style which is distributed with the package,
`___.nlo` is the raw information generated by latex on the first run, the `-o`
option instructs `makeindex` to write the sorted/formatted version to `___.nls`
which is then input by latex on the second run.

Your editor may have a way of customising this to a button or menu, but just typing it in the terminal works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TeXShop it's *very* easy: add some lines to your document as shown below.

```
% !TEX TS-program = Arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Here is some text, where we use APC.
\nomenclature{APC}{antigeen-presenterende cel}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Then ensure that the dropdown menu next to the “Typeset” button says “Arara”. Press “Typeset”. Et voilà.

If you have MacTeX 2013 or later and TeXShop 3.48, it should work out of the box; if not, go to the folder

```
~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Arara
```

and move the `arara.engine` file to

```
~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/
```

that is, two levels up. In this case you have to restart TeXShop for the change to be recognized.

If the system asks you to install Java, do it. Note that `~` refers to your Home folder.

Comment: Thanks, but i do not have the folders ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Arara. I do however have a folder named Tex, but it doesn't contain a foler named engines??

Comment: @Rasmus What version of TeXShop are you running?

Comment: I'm running Version 3.48.1

Comment: Quit TeXShop and move the `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` folder to the trash. Then restart TeXShop, which should recreate the folder with the correct structure.

Comment: "Then ensure that the dropdown menu next to the “Typeset” button says “Arara” - What if it does not?

Comment: @Pawel You wouldn't be using Arara when clicking the “Typeset” button.

Comment: For people that are still struggling with with this on TexShop, here is the solution that worked for me: there is no need to use arara. All I did was the following: change "Latex" (located in the dropdown menu next to the "typeset" button) to "pdflatexmk" and hit "typeset."

Answer (score 0):

On your texmaker window, click on options, configure texmaker, then under makeIndex ensure you have.

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
```

click ok

Then run you tex file using the following - `PDFlatex` - `MakeIndex` - `PDFlatex` - `Quickbuild(view pdf)` in that order.

Thank you.

David.