# How to create list of abbreviations in latex?

Tags: winedt, nomenclature

I want to create List of Abbreviations in my thesis document. I am using winedit for writing.  When I use new abbreviation in my document then it will come in List of Abbreviations page automatically?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your document setup and what you've tried so far. Reproducing the problem and finding out what you would need is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See the [acronym](https://www.ctan.org/topic/acronym) and [glossary](https://www.ctan.org/topic/glossary) topics on CTAN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of abbreviations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100354)

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you meant **WinEdt** instead of **Winedit** as editor you can install the Add-On [Nomenclature](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Nomenclature.html) which works for the `nomencl` as well as for the `nomentbl` package.

Assuming that you are using *PDFTeXify* to create your output this macro is modified in that way, that it will automatically compile the nomenclature when needed. In seldom cases this fails, but there is in addition added a button to create the nomenclature, which can then be pressed.